# QPainter painter object outside paintevent

Tags: visual-c++, qt5, qpainter

I am trying to draw a simple two dimensional figure in a `QWidget` window.
There is a `paintEvent` defined and a painter object of the `QPainter` class is also defined.
My drawing contains elements which I need to draw more than once at various locations, such as lines, text etc. For this purpose, I am using functions to draw these lines with varying positions. Similarly for text. In order to make the program shorter, also modular.

The `paintEvent` function is calling functions which are used to calculate and draw.

How do I pass the `QPainter` painter object defined in the `paintEvent` into the functions.

for e.g.

```
void Classname::drawText(QString text, int PosX, int PosY, QPainter painter)
{
    QSize size=this->size();

    QFont times("Helvetica [Cronyx]", 10);
    QFontMetrics box(times);

    int boxWidth = box.width(text);
    int boxHeight = box.height();

    painter.setFont(times);
    painter.setPen(Qt::white);
    painter.drawText(PosX,PosY,text);
}
```

then I get an error where the vc++ environment is telling me that the typename is not allowed for the painter object of `QPainter` class.

If I define `QPainter` painter1 object as shown below:

```
void Classname::drawText(QString text, int PosX, int PosY, QPainter painter)
{
    QPainter painter1;

    QSize size=this->size();

    QFont times("Helvetica [Cronyx]", 10);
    QFontMetrics box(times);

    int boxWidth = box.width(text);
    int boxHeight = box.height();

    painter.setFont(times);
    painter.setPen(Qt::white);
    painter.drawText(PosX,PosY,text);
}
```

the program compiles but there is no output.

This is a part of the code, I am defining objects of the `QPainter` class in all the functions.

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915497/creating-one-qpainter-object-and-using-it-in-paintevent), but the instructions are not clear. Must the `begin()` and `end()` function be called at all instances of drawing or just once in the `paintEvent` function?

Comment: I found out myself, the painter object can be passed as QPainter& painter. Then it works alright.

Comment: You can also store painter "programs" inside a `QPicture`. You then simply replay it within your `paintEvent`. Another way is to use `QPainterPath` to store reusable, scalable vector graphics.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you shall implement those functions in your class.

In your header:

```
class Class
{
// ...
protected:
    virtual void paintEvent( QPaintEvent* aEvent ) override;

private:
    void drawText( QPainter* aPainter, const QString& aText, int aPosX, int aPosY );
    // void drawLine( ... );
};
```

In your source:

```
void Class::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* aEvent )
{
    QPainter painter( this );

    // ...
    drawText( &painter/*, ... */ );
    drawLine( &painter/*, ... */ );
}

void Class::drawText( QPainter* aPainter, const QString& aText, int aPosX, int aPosY )
{
    // Your drawing ...
}
```