# Why is QPainter not drawing to my QWidget?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qpainter

I'm trying to draw a line on my window but I haven't been able to get anything to actually draw.

My .h

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <Disc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class Board
{
    private:
        int currentDiscs;   
        Disc* discArray[64];
        char* first;
        QWidget* window;
    public:
        Board(int*);
        int StartDrawing(QApplication*);

};

#endif

}
```

My .cpp

```
int Board::StartDrawing(QApplication* app) 
{
int WIDTH = 640;
int HEIGHT = 800;

QWidget* window = new QWidget();

window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent, true);
window->setFixedSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
window->setWindowTitle("Title!");

this->window = window;
window->show();

QPainter* painter = new QPainter(window);
//QPixmap pixmap1("\\images\\tile_1.png");

//painter->drawPixmap(QPoint(0,0), pixmap1);  // this works
painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
painter->drawLine(10,10,100,500);
delete painter;

return app->exec();
}
```

My guess is that I'm missing something with my QPainter but I haven't seen anything online to suggest I need call any other functions with it.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always useful to [read the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#custom-widgets-and-painting), yours is the most frequently made mistake:

> Each widget performs all painting operations from within its
>   paintEvent() function. This is called whenever the widget needs to be
>   redrawn, either as a result of some external change or when requested
>   by the application.

You must only paint on a widget from that widget's paint event. Other paint devices are less restricted, you can paint from everywhere to another paint device, and if needed, paint that cache to a widget in its paint event. Note that on some platforms `QPixmap` might not support drawing from a thread other than the main thread.

Comment: I spent a good amount of time researching the paintEvent docs and found through several articles that you can set the PaintOutsidePaintEvent attribute to true, which enables painting outside of a QWidget's PaintEvent.

`window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent, true);`

So I don't see why I can't use my QPainter outside of the paintEvent since I've set its attribute prior to 'painting'.

Comment: Here's a link to one of the articles... The comment is at the bottom.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/4932/a-question-about-paintevent-function/6

The comment is fairly old, but it was Qt 4 so I assumed it was still valid, plus I'm not having any compilation or runtime errors.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't work as intended. It is legacy stuff that has been removed from Qt 5 and back when it was still in Qt the recommendation was to only use it when porting Qt 3 code. Simply paint in the paint event as it is supposed.

Answer (score 0):

So previously [my research](https://forum.qt.io/topic/4932/a-question-about-paintevent-function/6) had taught me that if I implemented the setAttribute function:

```
QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent, true);
```

My QPainter would be able to print outside of a `QWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)` function call.

Dtech pointed out that it was a legacy function and no longer existed within Qt 5. As I was compiling in Qt 4.8.7 on Ubuntu I had figured the functionality still existed and managed to find the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html) (ctrl+f PaintOutsidePaintEvent).

WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent:

> Makes it possible to use QPainter to paint on the widget outside paintEvent(). This flag is not supported on Windows, Mac OS X or Embedded Linux. We recommend that you use it only when porting Qt 3 code to Qt 4.

So one must assume this attribute setting will only operate properly when porting Qt 3 code to Qt 4.

Thus, the error was in trying to implement the QWidget::setAttribute function INSTEAD of [overriding the paintEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253980/qpainter-painter-object-outside-paintevent) function of my QWidget.